# ElasticSearch / Highlighting the matched part in the query, not the hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know what part of **my query** has been useful for the hits, and present it to my users.

Exemple query : "awesome quick fox"

- Hit 1 : "the quick brown fox" --> "awesome [quick] [fox]"
- Hit 2 : "the quick dog" --> "awesome [quick] fox"
- Hit 3 : "the foxes" --> "awesome quick [fox]"

I know how to highlight in the results, but I want to know what part of the query was "useful".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [explanation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) of the results by adding `"explain": true` to the root of your query. This way you can see how the score is computed for each hit and know which part of the query influences more in the final score.

Comment: Hi. Actually I want to use the extracted data and present it to the user : 
Is there a way to have a simple array / object containing the data, a bit like "highlight" ?

Comment: Sorry! I can't help you then. I misunderstood the question, I thought you were more like debugging the query, in order to see how useful each part of the query is.